# Authorize Attribute w/ Roles not working properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[Authorize (Roles="group1")]

will not allow group1.

also, if I do Roles.IsUserInRole("group1"), its false despite the users role correctly identified in asp.net membership db.

what could i be missing?

EDIT:  if I do this I can read the role, but not as above: Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser("username")

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a RoleProvider configured?  Is the connection string for the RoleProvider pointed at the proper database with the correct credentials?  Membership and Role Providers perform different functions and having a membership provider configured won't automatically give you role information.

Comment: yes using aspnetsqlroleprovider and connection string is good

Answer (score 1):

if your using in the aspx page u will need this ..... where admin is my role assigned ...

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")
```

and in the controller if u want to use ....

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

where admin is the role i have assigned

and if u still aren't able to get it working try [this](http://rtur.net/blog/post/2009/06/03/Quick-and-dirty-role-management-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) post...

if still the problem persists try posting your web.config and page where u r having problem